# Look for file names that match a rule with Applescript

Tags: applescript

A client has a massive WordPress uploads folder with 7 or 8 size versions of each file.

I'm looking to filter out all images that have `-NNNxNNN` as part of the file name - "NNN" being any number. For eg:

- Originally uploaded file: `7Metropolis711.jpg`
- Example resized version of same file: `7Metropolis711-792x373.jpg`

I'm using Automator for this, and I'm just looking for the Applescript to filter out those files from the inputted folder of files.. IE:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want each set of sizes sorted at the same time on the single run of the workflow. Or a single size set on a single run of the workflow

Comment: I only want the original. So the assumption is that any image with "-NNNxNNN", is a resized image and can be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
on run {input}
    set newList to {}
    repeat with aFile in input
        tell application "System Events" to set fileName to name of aFile
        try
            set variableName to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of fileName & " | grep -Eo [0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}"
        on error
            set end of newList to (aFile's contents)
        end try
    end repeat
    return newList
end run
```

[image]

Comment: we have a winner! :) Thank you very much adayzdone.

i want to run it again, but this time find NNxNN in the filename, so I assume I just change your grep stuff from {3} to {2} ?

Comment: Also, do you know what data "Copy Finder Items" is looking for after your script runs? http://f.markb.me/mXaJ

Comment: Yes, you can change {3} to {2} to look for 2 numbers. You can also change the regular expression to [0-9]*x[0-9]* to catch any number of numbers followed by x followed by any number of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can see a handler "isFormatNNNxNNN(fileName)" which tests the file name for your format. Obviously remove the first 2 lines of the code. They're used so I could test this in AppleScript Editor. They should equal your input variable in Automator.

***EDIT***: based on your comments I modified the script to account for more than one "-" in the file name. Now I start looking at the text in front of the file extension since I assume your format is the last characters in the file name.

It didn't work in Automator because you have to put "on run {input, parameters}" around the code. I have done that now so just copy/paste this into automator.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set newList to {}
    repeat with aFile in input
        if not (my isFormatNNNxNNN(aFile)) then set end of newList to (contents of aFile)
    end repeat
    return newList
end run

on isFormatNNNxNNN(theFile)
    set theBool to false
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            set fileName to name of theFile
            set fileExt to name extension of theFile
        end tell

        set endIndex to (count of fileExt) + 2
        set nameText to text -(endIndex + 7) thru -endIndex of fileName
        if nameText starts with "-" then
            if character 5 of nameText is "x" then
                -- test for numbers
                text 2 thru 4 of nameText as number
                text 6 thru 8 of nameText as number
                set theBool to true
            end if
        end if
    end try
    return theBool
end isFormatNNNxNNN
```

Comment: Thanks Regulus. It says the variable input is not defined - assuming because the action above this script isn't sending the files as "input", but as some other variable.

See here: http://f.markb.me/ozN6 - any ideas what it should change to?

Comment: Actually, by leaving in those first 2 lines, it seems to run fine! Busy processing 1.something gb's of images now...

Thanks again!

Comment: Actually no, no joy... The results seem to send back everything... See here: http://f.markb.me/Tf7A

It should return the yellow highlighted item and ignore everything else...

Comment: I modified the code in my answer. As I can see now the filenames have more than 1 "-" in them. You didn't mention that!

Comment: Thanks again regulus. Busy re-running the script and no errors so far. Appreciate your help sir :)